# "cp" is not working

Tags: command-line, directory, cp

I am a newcomer in Linux. I tried to copy a file into another directory but it says that the directory does not exist.

I tried this:

```
cp b / vlsi
```

Here `b` is the file which is at another directory named `mas` and I am quite sure that `vlsi` is a directory.

What is the error of my code?

Comment: Try `cp b vlsi/`. However, that supposes that the file `b` is in your current directory, and so is the sub-directory `vlsi`.

Comment: In that case, `vlsi` is a subdirectory of your home directory and can be addressed as `~/vlsi`, with `~` short for `/home/yourusername`. So the copy command should be `cp b ~/vlsi/`.

Comment: Try again. You probably typed a space between `~` and `/vlsi/`.

Comment: you are right thanks..can you please provide me an answer for this:     cp: cannot create regular file ‘/./b’: Permission denied

Comment: You must have made another typo, because now you are trying to copy the file b to the root directory `/` (the extra `./` does nothing). The command `cp b ~/vlsi/` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command is `cp b vlsi/` meaning: copy the file `b` into the directory `vlsi`.

If the file `b` or the target directory are not in the current directory (the directory from which you are issuing the command), you need to give the whole path. In your case, the directory `vlsi` is not in the current directory, but in your home directory. So the full command becomes:

```
cp b /home/yourusername/vlsi/
```

However, instead of typing `/home/yourusername` you can simply type the symbol `~`. So this command does the same thing:

```
cp b ~/vlsi/
```